# Create a function after a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

So, I'd like to create a library package for Node that selects some element and passes it on to the next function. Although, you can use it for other related functions.

Here's an example of what I'd want.

```js
Selector(element).Action(options, callback);
```

In practice, it would be like this;

```js
cont arr = [1, 2, 3];
Q(arr).insert(4, function (newArr, lengthIndex) {
    console.log(newArr); // => [1,2,3,4]
    console.log(lengthIndex); // => 4
});
```

So, I was wondering how you could make the `Action()` function inside of the `Selector` function. I'd also like to still be able to use `Q(element)` to return a custom object for that. I was thinking of returning an object with the functions and custom stuff inside of that, but I'm not sure though.

```js
const Q = function (Element) {
    return {
        type:   typeof Element,
        length: Element.length,

        // Functions
        insert: function (Attribute, Callback) {
            Element.push(Attribute);
            Callback(Element, Element.length);
            return Element;
        }
    };

}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. The library will be enhanced functions and information about specific stuff, will also feature HTTP requests. I'm going for a jQuery-style package, and was wondering if there was another way.

~Q

Comment: Whats not working for you with this approach?

Comment: In its current state, it's working fine. I was wondering if there was another approach to this question, like using classes and such how @Pavel Shirobok said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls `chaining`. And the best approach to do this use the classes with required methods, which will returns it's self `return this`, or create new one/other class's instances like `return new Action(someData)` in called methods. If you dont want to use classes from outside, you can create function wrappers for creating instances and returning it:

```
class Selection{

constructor(args){
  this.args = args;
}

doWork(){
  console.log(this.args);
  return this;
}
}


function select(...args){
   return new Selection(args);
}

select("something").doWork()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood that correctly. Could you clarify/edit your answer? I'd like to know which action functions I can specify with the type of `Element`. For instance, the action `insert` is available on Arrays, but not strings.

Comment: @QSmally it's fully depends on your task.

Comment: Ok. So, if I understood it correctly, I create different classes for each element I'd like to add - Such as Arrays, string manipulation, and other functions. Then I switch between the different classes depending on the element type?